# Make first index's value of array as a key and second index's value as value of new array

Tags: php, codeigniter

For below code:

```
 $data = $student_internal_mark->$internalmark_col;
        $d = explode("|",$data);
        foreach ($d as $value) {
              $register_no_arr = explode(":",$value);
              $marks = explode(',',$register_no_arr[1]);
              print_r($register_no_arr);
        }
```

I got output as below:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => SD00000001
            [1] => 9.8,3,2,3,4
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => SD00000002
            [1] => 6.8,2.4,34,34,34
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => SD00000003
            [1] => 4.6,2.4,23,23,23
        )
        Array
        (
            [0] => SD00000004
            [1] => 6.4,1.2,32,32,32
        )
```

I want to retrieve the values in such a way that i will get (output) an array as:

```
student_marks[SD00000001]=9.8,3,2,3,4
student_marks[SD00000002]=6.8,2.4,34,34,34
student_marks[SD00000003]=4.6,2.4,23,23,23
.......
student_marks[SD0000000N]=................
```

So that I can display marks in each array, as given below

### Register No | Mark 1 | Mark 2 |Mark 3 | Total

S5001       | 3 | 2 | 3 | 8

S5002       |4 | 4 |6 | 14

S5003       |1 |3 |5 | 9

Comment: `echo $register_no_arr[0];` and `echo $register_no_arr[1];` echo this and let me know what you get?

Comment: $register_no_arr[0] = $register_no_arr[1];
              print_r( $register_no_arr); For this ??

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 9.8,3,2,3,4
    [1] => 9.8,3,2,3,4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6.8,2.4,34,34,34
    [1] => 6.8,2.4,34,34,34
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use foreach. Try this:

```
$arr = array(
  array("SD00000001", "9.8,3,2,3,4"),
  array("SD00000002", "6.8,2.4,34,34,34"),
  array("SD00000003", "4.6,2.4,23,23,23"),
  array("SD00000004", "6.4,1.2,32,32,32"),
);

$student_marks = array();
foreach($arr as $values) {
    $student_marks[$values[0]] = $values[1];
}

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($student_marks);
echo '</pre>';
```

**UPDATE**

This is your given:

```
$data = 'SD00000001:9.8,3,2,3,4|SD00000002:6.8,2.4,34,34,34|SD000000‌​03:4.6,2.4,23,23,2‌​3|‌​SD00000004:6.4,1.2,3‌​2,32,32'; 
$student_marks = array();
$d = explode("|",$data);
foreach($d as $values) {
    $valuesArr = explode(":", $values);
    $student_marks[$valuesArr[0]] = $valuesArr[1];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($student_marks); 
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: How to get array in this format ?? $arr = array(
  array("SD00000001", "9.8,3,2,3,4"),......

Comment: its the same with your $register_no_arr don't worry, that is my way of formatting arrays, i just interpreted your array variable into mine. ^_^

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 2005SD00000014
    [1] => 5.8,1.8,29,29,29
    [2] => 0
    [5] => .
)

Comment: Try to check first your $register_no_arr if your getting the correct format before using my snippet.

Comment: I used this code: $data = 'SD00000001:9.8,3,2,3,4|SD00000002:6.8,2.4,34,34,34|SD00000003:4.6,2.4,23,23,23|SD00000004:6.4,1.2,32,32,32';
    $d = explode("|",$data);
    foreach ($d as $value) {
    $register_no_arr = explode(":",$value);
 $arr = $register_no_arr;
 $student_marks = $register_no_arr;
 foreach($arr as $values) {
    $student_marks[$values[0]] = $values[1];
 }
 }
    print_r($student_marks);
 exit;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129317/discussion-between-l-herrera-and-dayana-benny).

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_walk, demo [here](https://eval.in/687382).

```
   <?php
    $register_no_arr = array(
      array("SD00000001", "9.8,3,2,3,4"),
      array("SD00000002", "6.8,2.4,34,34,34"),
      array("SD00000003", "4.6,2.4,23,23,23"),
      array("SD00000004", "6.4,1.2,32,32,32"),
    );


    $o = [];
    array_walk($register_no_arr, function($v) use(&$o)
    {
      $o[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    });
    var_dump($o);
```

result:

```
array(4) {
  ["SD00000001"]=>
  string(11) "9.8,3,2,3,4"
  ["SD00000002"]=>
  string(16) "6.8,2.4,34,34,34"
  ["SD00000003"]=>
  string(16) "4.6,2.4,23,23,23"
  ["SD00000004"]=>
  string(16) "6.4,1.2,32,32,32"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you your expected array

```
$str = "S5001:31,32,33|S5002:42,44,46|S5003:21,23,25";
$d = explode("|",$str);

foreach ($d as $value) {
        $register_no_arr = explode(":",$value);
        $marks[$register_no_arr[0]] = $register_no_arr[1];

}

print_r($marks);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [S5001] => 31,32,33
    [S5002] => 42,44,46
    [S5003] => 21,23,25
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach ($d as $value) {
              $register_no_arr = explode(":",$value);
              $new_arr['student_marks']$register_no_arr[0] = $register_no_arr[1];
        }

print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this...

```
     $student_marks = array(
        '1' => array(
            '0' => 'SD00000001',
            '1' => '9.8,3,2,3,4',
        ),
        '2'=>array(

          '0' => 'SD00000002',
           '1' => '6.8,2.4,34,34,34',
        ),
        '3'=> array (
            '0' => 'SD00000003',
            '1' => '4.6,2.4,23,23,23',
        )
    );

    foreach ($student_marks as $key => $value) {
        $student_marks1[$value['0']] = $value['1'];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($student_marks1);
```